# Copy Complete Webbrowser element?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

Hello I am trying to copy an Element inside  Webbrowser1, it is :

```
<div id="mydiv">
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="MyScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="MyScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="MyScript"></script>
<iframe>....</iframe>
</div>
```

I try to copy it with my code:

```
dim elementCopy = WebBrowser1.Document.All("mydiv").InnerHtml
richtextbox1.appendtext(elementCopy)
```

But it only copies `<iframe>....</iframe>`.
Is there a way to be able to copy all of the Element like in Chrome CopyElement in DeveloperMode?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working...so easy, Simply changed from
.Innerhtml to .outterhtml.

Thanks Guys!